# any quick sorting for a huge csv file

Tags: java, unix, sorting, csv

I am looking some java implementation of sorting algorithm. The file could be HUGE, say 20000*600=12,000,000 lines of records. The line is comma delimited with 37 fields and we use 5 fields as keys. Is it possible to sort it quickly, say 30 minutes?

If you got other approach other than java, it is welcome if it can be easily integrated into java system. For example, unix utility.

Thanks.

Edit: The lines need to be sort is dispersed into 600 files, with 20000 lines each, 4mb for each file. Finally I would like them to be 1 big sorted file.

I am trying to time a unix sort, would update that afterwards.

Edit:

I appended all the files into a big one, and tried the unix sort function, it is pretty good. The time to sort a 2gb file is 12-13 minutes. The append action require 4 minutes for 600 files.

```
sort -t ',' -k 1,1 -k 4,7 -k 23,23 -k 2,2r big.txt -o sorted.txt
```

Comment: "The files need to be sort is dispersed "?  Does this mean 600 files must be merged together for the sort?  Or does this mean that the sorted file must be split into 600 files?

Comment: You was thinking too much...now it is okay. I got it done with unix sort.

Comment: "You was thinking too much"?  What does "The files need to be sort is dispersed into 600 files" actually mean?  Either explain it or remove it from the question.

Comment: I was just trying to explain the situation of the files for the good of the readers to this question. And well I think I should had write "The lines need to be sort is dispersed into 600 files" instead of "The files need to be sort is dispersed into 600 files" because that is confusing indeed. If I didn't state the situation, I think someone will stand out and ask how were the files organized in order to get an optimal approach.

Comment: Depending on the actual data, setting LC_ALL=C will speed up sort on unix. I've noticed speed-ups of 30%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does the data get in the CSV format? Does it come from a relational database? You can make it such that whatever process creates the file writes its entries in the right order so you don't have to solve this problem down the line.

If you are doing a simple lexicographic order you can try the unix `sort`, but I am not sure how that will perform on a file with that size.

Comment: I tried the unix sort, it is slower than my expectation. Maybe the records is just too much.

Comment: @gunbuster363: show the actual command you used and the actual timing you got and the time that you require.  Please **udpate** the question with these additional facts.  Please don't make us guess randomly what you did.

Answer (score 2):

Calling unix sort program should be [efficient](http://vkundeti.blogspot.com/2008/03/tech-algorithmic-details-of-unix-sort.html).  It does multiple passes to ensure it is not a memory hog.  You can fork a process with java's Runtime, but the outputs of the process are redirected, so you have to some juggling to [get the redirect to work right](http://ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/java/online/io/javazine.html):

```
public static void sortInUnix(File fileIn, File sortedFile)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String[] cmd = {
           "cmd", "/c", 
           // above should be changed to "sh", "-c" if on Unix system
           "sort " + fileIn.getAbsolutePath() + " > "
               + sortedFile.getAbsolutePath() };

    Process sortProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

    // capture error messages (if any)
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        sortProcess.getErrorStream()));
    String outputS = reader.readLine();
    while (outputS != null) {
        System.err.println(outputS);
        outputS = reader.readLine();
    }

    sortProcess.waitFor();
}
```

Comment: Adding `"cmd", "/c"` was done to fork a windows cmd window which has cygwin's utilities in the path.  Depending on your OS and your specification of your input files, YMMV. You may not need to get the absolute path for the commands either.

Comment: Is it going to sort with respect to the first field of the CSV file ?

Comment: CanCeylan, It'll sort with respect to the first characters in each line of the file, which may differ from the first field if there are quote delimiters on some of the lines' first fields and not others.

Answer (score 2):

Use the java library [big-sorter](https://github.com/davidmoten/big-sorter) which is published to Maven Central and has an optional dependency on [commons-csv](https://github.com/apache/commons-csv) for CSV processing. It handles files of any size by splitting to intermediate files, sorting and merging the intermediate files repeatedly until there is only one left.  Note also that the max group size for a merge is configurable (useful for when there are a large number of input files).

Here's an example:

Given the CSV file below, we will sort on the second column (the "number" column):

```
name,number,cost
WIPER BLADE,35,12.55
ALLEN KEY 5MM,27,3.80
```

```java
Serializer<CSVRecord> serializer = Serializer.csv(
  CSVFormat.DEFAULT
     .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
     .withRecordSeparator("\n"),
  StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Comparator<CSVRecord> comparator = (x, y) -> {
    int a = Integer.parseInt(x.get("number"));
    int b = Integer.parseInt(y.get("number"));
    return Integer.compare(a, b);
};
Sorter 
  .serializer(serializer) 
  .comparator(comparator) 
  .input(inputFile) 
  .output(outputFile)
  .sort();
```

The result is:

```
name,number,cost
ALLEN KEY 5MM,27,3.80
WIPER BLADE,35,12.55
```

I created a CSV file with 12 million rows and 37 columns and filled the grid with random integers between 0 and 100,000. I then sorted the 2.7GB file on the 11th column using *big-sorter* and it took **8 mins** to do single-threaded on an i7 with SSD and max heap set at 512m (`-Xmx512m`).

See the project [README](https://github.com/davidmoten/big-sorter) for more details.

Comment: Hi @dave, what an absolutely amazing library is this. Thanks for creating it!

Answer (score 0):

[Java Lists can be sorted](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29), you can try starting there.

Comment: If I sort it in the list, I need to make HUGE list.....I think the memory is not enough??

Comment: @gunbuster363: When you tried it, did it fit in memory?  Please don't assume that it's too big.  Please actually build the list and see what actually happens.

Comment: I tried! Don't you say...see the power of "Out of Memory" error!

Answer (score 0):

Python on a big server.

```
import csv
def sort_key( aRow ):
    return aRow['this'], aRow['that'], aRow['the other']
with open('some_file.csv','rb') as source:
   rdr= csv.DictReader( source )
   data = [ row for row in rdr ]
   data.sort( key=sort_key )
   fields= rdr.fieldnames
with open('some_file_sorted.csv', 'wb') as target:
   wtr= csv.DictWriter( target, fields }
   wtr.writerows( data )
```

This should be reasonably quick.  And it's very flexible.

On a small machine, break this into three passes: decorate, sort, undecorate

Decorate:

```
import csv
def sort_key( aRow ):
    return aRow['this'], aRow['that'], aRow['the other']
with open('some_file.csv','rb') as source:
   rdr= csv.DictReader( source )
   with open('temp.txt','w') as target:
       for row in rdr:
           target.write( "|".join( map(str,sort_key(row)) ) + "|" + row )
```

Part 2 is the operating system sort using "|" as the field separator

Undecorate:

```
with open('sorted_temp.txt','r') as source:
   with open('sorted.csv','w') as target:
       for row in rdr:
           keys, _, data = row.rpartition('|')
           target.write( data )
```

Comment: Except that any in-memory sorting algorithm will just plain fail with an out of memory error for any even medium large data set (12E6 lines w/ say 500bytes per line would result in 5.6gb for the data only)

Comment: @Voo:  Not necessarily. 12M records may fit in memory on many machines.  12M  * .5K is 6Gb.

Comment: @S. Lott: Well I went along the lines that anyone depicting 12M records as "HUGE" input wouldn't work with a 200gb server (heck I've worked on 2tb cluster where you wouldn't even miss the memory). But since he specified the file and its only 2.4gb there won't be any problem - I fear I have a different definition of "huge" ;)

Comment: @Voo: Words like "huge" don't mean anything.  Until they actually get an actual out-of-memory error, their analysis doesn't mean much.  2.4Gb on disk doesn't correlate well with "in memory".  String intern may reduce the memory footprint to 12M references to just a few distinct String objects.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention platform, so it is hard to come to terms with the time specified.  12x10^6 records isn't that many, but sorting is a pretty intensive task.  Let's say 37 fields, say 100bytes/field would be 45GB?  That's a bit much for most machines, but if the records average 10bytes/field your server should be able to fit the entire file in RAM, which would be ideal.

My suggestion: Break the file into chunks that are 1/2 the available RAM, sort each chunk, then merge-sort the resulting sorted chunks.  This lets you do all of your sorting in memory rather than hitting swap, which is what I suspect of causing any slow-down.

Say (1G chunks, in a directory you can play around in):

```
split --line-bytes=1000000000 original_file chunk
for each in chunk* 
do
  sort $each > $each.sorted
done
sort -m chunk*.sorted > original_file.sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

As your data set is huge as you have mentioned. Sorting it all at one go will be time consuming depending on your machine (If you try QuickSort).
But since you would like it to be done within 30 mins. I would suggest that you have a look at Map Reduce  using 
[Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) as your application server.

Please keep in mind it's not an easy approach, but in the longer run you can easily scale up depending upon your data size.
I am also pointing you to an excellent link on [Hadoop setup](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/)

Work your way through single node setup and move to Hadoop cluster.
I would be glad to help you if you get stuck anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You really do need to make sure you have the right tools for the job. ( Today, I am hoping to get a 3.8 GHz PC with 24 GB memory for home use. It been a while since I bought myself a new toy. ;)

However, if you want to sort these lines and you don't have enough hardware, you don't need to break up the data because its in 600 files already.

Sort each file individually, then do a 600-way merge sort (you only need to keep 600 lines in memory at once)  Its not as simple as doing them all at once, but you could probably do it on a mobile phone. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 600 smaller files, it could be faster to sort all of them concurrently.  This will eat up 100% of the CPU.  That's the point, correct?

```
waitlist= 
for f in ${SOURCE}/*
do 
    sort -t ',' -k 1,1 -k 4,7 -k 23,23 -k 2,2r -o ${f}.srt ${f} &
    waitlist="$waitlist $!"
done
wait $waitlist
LIST=`echo $SOURCE/*.srt`
sort --merge -t ',' -k 1,1 -k 4,7 -k 23,23 -k 2,2r -o sorted.txt ${LIST}
```

This will sort 600 small files all at the same time and then merge the sorted files.  It may be faster than trying to sort a single large file.

Comment: Doing in this way double the time needed. For the upper part, it elapsed 12 minutes, and for the lower part, it elapsed for 23 minutes.

Comment: @gunbuster363: I've modified the solution to sort all 600 in parallel instead of sorting them serially.  However, since the 600-file merge is too slow, there's really nothing gained through parallel sorts of the original 600 files.

Answer (score 0):

Use Map/Reduce Hadoop to do the sorting..  i recommend Spring Data Hadoop. Java.

Answer (score -1):

Well since you're talking about HUGE datasets this means you'll need some external sorting algorithm anyhow. There are some for java and pretty much any other language out there - since the result will have to be stored on the disk anyhow which language you're using is pretty uninteresting.